# Upgrade powershell version 2.0 to version 4.0+ using cmd or powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, script, powershell-2.0

I have a problem, I work in a large organization we have several computers with windows 7 and many of them are very old versions, and come with a powershell 2.0.
I was creating some scripts to solve some problems and automate tasks, but some functions are only available in version 4.0+.
Does anyone know how to update powershell to version 4.0+ and download its dependencies via command line ( cmd or ps1). In the scenario I'm in, we have a WDS but without the automatic update of NET FRAMEWORK because it weighs more than 2tb on the server

I didn't find solutions that were 100% compatible only with CLI most need the user to do something on the screen

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://catonrug.blogspot.com/2017/04/powershell-5-silent-install.html

Comment: It is often very expensive to try to save money by working with out-of-date, way past end-of-life systems. It is not going to get easier or less expensive.